# How is "Is there a Day9 for League of Legends?" off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

[Is there a Day9 for league of legends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97635/is-there-a-day9-for-league-of-legends)

I have tried to engage the users who voted to close in comments with no success.

I have always been a huge advocate of these sites, however this type of behavior makes me want to delete my account.

I don't want to support a community where you can't even ask a simple question.

Comment: I agree that if we're going to cast close and downvotes on a question, a comment should be left behind explaining the reason. What you've had must be a very frustrating experience.

Comment: At it's heart, this question is asking for links to an outside resource; rather than being a specific problem about playing a game.

Comment: @KatieK Can you explain why asking for help finding outside resources is inappropriate?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't see how searching for links *is* appropriate for this site. An answer with a resource will be in danger of link-rot. If there's a question about a given strategy, that's great!

Comment: @KatieK I guess I don't see the difference between asking for an external resource and asking "how do I find X" type questions, which we do allow. (I concede there *may* be a difference—I just don't see one right now.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - The difference is about what's inside the game world versus real world culture which springs up as a result of the game.

Comment: @KatieK No, sorry, I wrote that ambiguously. I meant that "How do I find X" questions generally seem to be allowed, not just Qs on how to find virtual in-game things. See for example [How do I find trustworthy players in EVE Online](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95402/how-do-i-find-trustworthy-players-in-eve-online) and [How do I find mods for Civilization 5?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/how-do-i-find-mods-for-civilization-5). If asking how to find mods is OK, I don't see why asking for gameplay videos of a specific kind is off-topic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - Both of those questions ask "How do I find a resource", rather than "Is there a video I'd like".

Comment: Day9's website is a gaming resource. Probably one of the best.

Comment: @KatieK The edited question is a bit different, if you haven't looked at it recently. It's asking not for a video they'd subjectively find pleasing, but for a match-analysis resource in a video series format. I'd agree totally if it was "Is there a video I'd like"!

Answer (score 15):

Although I wasn't one of the close voters, your question is asking for a recommendation, which most of our user base feels shouldn't be allowed in any shape or form. Although I'm not going to go into all the details on why this is the case, the main reason is that they fall under **bad subjective**, which means there can be no one right answer, and it's just people posting "I like X best" answers with no backing.

As for your specific question, I think in it's current wording it would be **Not Constructive.** The reason for this is because you haven't given any criteria for *why* you like Day9, just "I like Day9, suggest something similiar." This is *very* similiar to a game recommendation question, which are off-topic here due to being purely subjective.

With that said, I believe your question *may* salvageable, although I'm sure some of user base is going to disagree (some users hate recommendation in any shape or form, no exceptions). If you can include more detail in your answer about exactly *what* you're looking for, and why, then I believe your question can cross over the line from **bad subjective** to **good subjective** *(which means subjective questions where answers are *still* supported by facts)*.

I'm not saying that *will* fix the problem, but it *might*. The reason I think it might is due to the fact that I think what you're looking for is a resource which will help you become a better player, and expanding your understanding of the game, something Day9 does very well with Starcraft 2. Although it may be borderline, I feel as if this crosses the line into a practical problem which can be solved, and crosses the line into good subjective. Furthermore, I feel as if such a question would be *extremely* useful to any new LoL player, and not just you.

I'd like to end by once against stating this ***might*** fix your question, it's not a guarantee.

Comment: Always with the faster, better answers. :<

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh It's the tortoise sun glasses that make me so fast. [*tortoise shades*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/57Nf2.png)

Comment: "The reason for this is because you haven't given any criteria for why you like Day9" ... but yes he has: *excellent match analysis*

Comment: @Decency Define "excellent match analysis" in a non-subjective (or at worst, Good Subjective) way.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh High level player with experience in analysis doing the so in a serious manner.

Answer (score 9):

The Off Topic rule is defined as a question not following the scope that our FAQ defines. The pertinent part of this, IMHO, is:

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Despite your protest to the contrary, the question is very much subjective. Day9's "charisma", as mentioned by the answer provided prior to close, is very much an individual thing. I know people that *hate* Day9 because he's "always too fucking happy". Asking "what individual in X community is most like this individual in Y community" is super nebulous and open to interpretation, and really hard to nail down in a way that Arqade covers.

There's also the fact that different people will think different things - the answer provided pre-closure cites TheOddOne as similar to Day9, whereas I couldn't imagine a more antithetical individual: Day9 is nowhere near the ragey, misogynist asshole that TOO is (though with Day9's frequent support of TotalBiscuit, I'm starting to change my mind on that).

All of this adds up to a fairly obvious OT closure.

Comment: Day9 analyzes pro sc2 matches. All i was asking is if there are members of the LoL community who do a similar show. Day9 releases new episodes constantly providing a very useful perspective on how recent patches and game changes are affecting high level play. In my opinion there would be 1 or 2 answers. I can see the misunderstanding now and could have rephrased my question to show that personality played no part in my question had anyone commented.

Comment: Day9's charisma is why he is so successful at what he does, but the question is about **what he does**, not his personality while doing it. He is an extremely high level player performing in-depth gameplay analysis on a very regular basis- there are some of those in LoL and it's thus an objectively answerable question. The matter of whether you like or hate his style is extraneous- even the vast majority of people who dislike his persona (and I count myself among them) will not dispute the quality of his analyses.